# How to increase jLabel value by one when incorrect value is entered

Tags: java, netbeans, jframe

I'm making a hangman game using a jFrame form, for the button that checks whether the letter you've entered is correct or not I'd also like it to be able to detect whether you've entered a wrong letter and subsequently add one to a label. What I have so far is this:

```
 private void tryLetterActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                          
        int charPos = 0;
        String letter = aLetter.getText();
        charPos = FindWord.indexOf(letter);
        MyMessage.setText("position is " + charPos);
        if (charPos == 0) Char0.setText(letter);
        if (charPos == 1) Char1.setText(letter);
        if (charPos == 2) Char2.setText(letter);
        if (charPos == 3) Char3.setText(letter);
        if (charPos == 4) Char4.setText(letter);


}
```

I can't figure out what to add to make it increase the label by one when a wrong letter is guessed

Comment: `if-else if-else`, maybe have a look at [The if-then and if-then-else Statements](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/if.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the same letter appears at different positions, you should have something like:

```
int errors = 0;

...

char letter = aLetter.getText().charAt(0);
if (findWord.indexOf(letter) != -1) {
    if (findWord.charAt(0) == letter) char0.setText(String.valueOf(letter));
    if (findWord.charAt(1) == letter) char1.setText(String.valueOf(letter));
    if (findWord.charAt(2) == letter) char2.setText(String.valueOf(letter));
    if (findWord.charAt(3) == letter) char3.setText(String.valueOf(letter));
    ...
} else {
    // Error:
    ++errors;
    label.setText(String.valueOf(error));
}
```

This can be done a bit more flexible with an array instead of char0, ~1, ~2 etcetera, and then using a for-loop.

Or simplify all in one text component which gets replaced from "...." to ".A.A" to ".A.A - wrong!" to "JA.A" or such.

Answer (score 0):

You need to compare if the letter they have entered is the same to the one as the one there trying to guess

```
if(aLetter.getText().equals("Letter trying to guess"){
   "Show blank letter"
}
else{
"Hangmans death"
}
```